# SQL Table Field settings for "TEXT"

Tags: mysql, sql, text

When choosing "TEXT" as a type for a field in SQL, what should the length/values be? I have always skipped that field but just thought it might be an unsafe thing...

Am I right or do i need to set it to a certain number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TEXT columns can have arbitrary length (for practical purposes, the length of a TEXT field is limited by available memory and buffers).

There is nothing inherently "unsafe" about TEXT columns. There are however a couple of caveats to be aware of, like MySQL only using the first 1024 bytes for sorting.

You can read more about all this on the the [official MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem leaving the length blank as TEXT is variable length only taking up as much space as needed. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html